# Description not available because of robots.txt on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags, google-search, robots.txt

I have some problems with the Google snippet description of my Rails app in Google search results. I get:

> A description for this result is not available because of this site’s robots.txt

I don't understand why I am getting this. I am not blocking the googlebot. Here's my robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Sitemap: https://s3-eu-west-1.******
```

and I also include this meta in my application.html file:

```
%meta{ name: 'description', content: "Le prix national Stars et Métiers est organisé en collaboration entre le groupe Banque Populaire et le réseau des CMA pour encourager l'excellence, l'audace et l'innovation, et mettre en lumière des chefs d'entreprises d'exception" }/
```

Why does Google not want to take into account my description?

UPDATE: when I am using this tool to see if my description is displaying, it works: https://totheweb.com/learning_center/tool-test-google-title-meta-description-lengths/

But when I try to find the website via the classic Google search, I still get "A description for this result is not available because of this site’s robots.txt".

Comment: What is the path it would be trying to fetch?

Comment: I am sorry @JonathanAllard, I dont get your question..

Comment: was robots.txt updated recently? If so, what was in the original manifest? Any changes to your site's on-page optimization will not be reflected until bots re-crawl your site.

Comment: no the robots.txt file has been there for a while and has not been changed...

Comment: @DavidGeismar Have you tried Google Robots.txt Tester? You can validate specific routes against your current robots.txt: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en